# Shopify webhook Cart update, Ruby/Sinatra

Tags: api, shopify

I am new to Shopify app development and i find their API guide very poor. 
What i want to accomplish is to add an handling fee which will be calculated based on cart total. 
I know that this can be done using webhooks but i cant find a real good example that show how a webhook works on shopify. 
So basically I will need to create a Cart update webook than catch every cart update webhook and do the stuff i need to do there. 
If someone can show me a sample (ruby Sinatra) would be great.

Comment: Hi Axheladini - I don't think you can just add such a figure to the cart total... the only way you can add to the total is by adding a product.  I've seen some people manage handling fees by adding the fee as a 'product' which is dynamically added to the cart based on total. Its clunky.... In which case you wouldn't need to use the app api... you could do this on the front end with the JavaScript api.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for your answer. Yes i was able to add a product on fly with javascript but that's not what I need because this way I am not able to update the price of the product i add.  Basically the handling fee is 5% of the total cart and i need to make the calculation and add the handling fee as a product. The only way to do this i by creating product variants on the fly and adding them to the cart through Shopify api using Cart update webhook. But i am not able to find a tutorial that shows how to work with webhooks on shopify api.   Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about Sinatra / Ruby (I'm in node land) - but its simple a case of posting some json to create the product.. https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/product and then I guess you'd use the javascript api to add it to the cart... but this could get very messy... - you'd need to remove the handling fee variant after checkout.. and you'd also need to hide them on the frontend

Comment: Yes its kind of messy but  i cant think for other way to do it. Is it possible to catch a webhook, lets when cart is update and to  add the handling fee (as a product) form the app with shopify api (not javascipt) ?

Comment: There isn't a cart update webhook. The JavaScript api allows you to update the cart - and gives you a callback - but thats not what you're after.

Comment: Have you had a look at Shopify Scripts? It's basically shopping cart rules for Shopify. Unfortunately though it is only available on Shopify Plus. API: https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/shopify-scripts GitHub examples: https://github.com/Shopify/scripts-examples